# Why can't I cd to a mapped drive using sftp?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, cygwin, sftp

I'm trying to upload a file to a mapped drive (D:) on a remote server using sftp.  I can RDP into that remote Windows 2012 server and see the D: drive in Explorer.  In a command shell I can also see it:

```
C:\cygwin\etc>mount
C:/cygwin/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin on / type ntfs (binary,auto)
C: on /cygdrive/c type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
D: on /cygdrive/d type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
```

Also, if I cd to that drive from the RDP command shell and then do a pwd, it shows what I expect.

```
D:\>pwd
/cygdrive/d
```

But when I sftp to it from my local Windows 10 laptop, I can't cd to the D drive.

```
sftp> cd /cygdrive/d
Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory
```

I'm logged in with sftp using same credentials as RDP.

Suggestions?

Comment: https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.shares

Comment: What sftp server software are you using?

Comment: @grawity: whatever comes with cygwin.  Installed within 1 year.

Comment: /cygdrive/d doesn't show up in WinSCP either.  Only /cygdrive/c shows up.

Comment: @matzeri: "This problem as well as its solution is described in detail in the Cygwin User's Guide".  Good luck finding it.

Comment: bottom of the link. `Switching the user context`

Comment: Why should I have to switch user context?  I'm using the same credentials that created the mapped network drive as the ones trying to access it.  I don't understand that, much less the gobbledygook that somehow explains how to do it.